# how to check whether user is login or not in Android Google+ sign in

Tags: android

I have LoginActivity and MainActivity.

in LoginActivity, there are Facebook LoginButton and Google+ LoginButton

In the case of Facebook login ,
I can check whether user is login or not in MainActivity

through this.

```
mToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

   if (mToken == null ){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

but i don't know how to check Google account.

is there any method like `mToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();`?

if not, how do i know whether users logged in or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        int statusCode = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
```

//                Get account information

```
            assert acct != null;
            String mEmail = acct.getEmail();
            String mUserId = acct.getId();
```

//                handleSignInResult(result);

```
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in this field... 
what handleSignInResult(result) means?
I already implemented this, but it is never used.

Comment: I want to know how to know in MainActivity

Comment: Use splash screen and shared preferences to check if he is logged in not